# What's loading more event on listview android xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

ex:
a=new string[]{a,b,c,d,e,f}

Default: listview just show from a to b.(a,b,c,d)
Now when I scroll down to at the bottom listview then display more e,f to listview.
result : a,b,c,d,e,f

What's that event? How to do that?

Comment: There is an ItemAppearing event in Xamarin.Forms, but you need specifically for Xamarin.Android, right?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the events for scrolling are:

- `Scroll`
- `ScrollChange`
- `ScrollStateChanged`,

**Edit:** Event `Scroll` has `FirstVisibleItem` and `VisibleItemCount` in the args. Example:

```
scrollView.Scroll += (sender, e) => {
    var firstIndex = e.FirstVisibleItem;
    var visibleCount = e.VisibleItemCount;
    var lastShownItemIndex = firstIndex + visibleCount;
}
```

Comment: But How to know scroll standing at bottom line

Comment: @J.Joe You need to know when user has scrolled to the bottom of the list?

Comment: that must check a position of data list?

Comment: Here you have a sample implementation of ScrollStateChanged https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/69432/#Comment_69432, as suggested by Artūrs Eimanis. Another example, with a bit more explanation is provided here: http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you create a custom ViewCell (which say "loading more...") add it to the end of the list and on its `OnAppearing` you know you arrived the last element and load next elements. Then put it before your element.